# Divergence of a series involving an operator

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $T$ be an operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$, $r$ be its spectral radius. Let $\phi$ be a positive linear functional on the algebra $B(H)$ of bounded operators on $H$ such that $\phi(I_H)=1$ and $\phi(S^*S)=0$ implies $S=0$. I wonder if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\phi(T^n)}{nr^n}$$
diverges?

Informally we can have $\phi(\log|T-rI|)$ which seems to diverge, but how should I prove it formally?

---

Jonas provided a nice counterexmaple where the series converges. But I think it is because he constructed an operator which has $i,-i$ as its spectrum, then the series is reduced to $\sum i^n/n$ and $\sum (-i)^n/n$ which both converge.

I wonder what if I assume $T$ has an eigenvalue which equals to $r$?

---

Jonas gave another counterexmaple. Please see the answer below. I admit that my intuition is for when $\phi$ is a trace and $T$ is a matrix, then $\phi(T^n)$ will be $\sum_i \lambda_i^n$, where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues. Then it will diverge. But what about a general operator with a general tracial positive linear functional?

This part can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552668/divergence-of-a-series-involving-an-operator-part-ii)

Comment: Since your original question was answered and the new version is harder to spot, and also because having answers to different questions in the same thread can get confusing, it may be worthwhile for you to ask a new question with the tracial condition on $\phi$.  (That is, it seems more likely to get you an answer and to make it clearer for readers later what is being answered.)  If you do so, please also link the questions to each other for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$, and let $\phi$ be defined by $\phi(A)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}\langle Ae_k,e_k\rangle$.  Let $T$ be the bounded operator such that $Te_1=e_2$, $Te_2=-e_1$, and $Te_k=0$ if $k>2$.  Then $r=1$, and $\phi(T^n)$ is $0$ when $n$ is odd, $-\frac34$ when $n$ is even and not a multiple of $4$, and $\frac34$ when $n$ is a multiple of $4$.  The series will converge by the alternating series test.

---

For the additional question, how about on $M_2$ this time, leaving out the details of extending the idea to $B(H)$, $\phi\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)=\frac12(a+d)-\frac14(b+c)$, and $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is very interesting! I guess it is because $i^n/n$ converges right? What if I force $T$ to have a point spectrum which is equal to the spectral radius?  I think in that case that would diverge then?

Comment: I mean $T$ has an eigenvalue which equals the spectral radius.

Comment: I don't know, that seems plausible.

Comment: @Fan: I updated with a counterexample for that case (on $M_2$ but it could be adjusted to fit $B(H)$ instead).

Comment: That's interesting! But I think for $S\in M_2$, $\phi(S^*S)=0$ only implies $a=b, c=d$?

Comment: @Fan: No, and I don't see where that comes from.  Every matrix of the form $S^*S$ is positive semidefinite.  If $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite then $a$ and $d$ are nonnegative, $c=\overline b$, and $ad\geq |b|^2$, so $|b|\leq\sqrt{ad}\leq\frac12(a+d)$.  Hence $b+c=2\mathrm{Re}(b)\leq 2|b|\leq a+d$.  Hence $\frac14(b+c)\leq\frac14(a+d)\leq\frac12(a+d)$, with equality only if $a=d=0$, which in turn implies $A=0$.

Comment: That is correct! I made a mistake in calculation. My last hope is: what if $\phi$ is tracial, that is to say, $\phi(ST)=\phi(TS)$ for any $S,T$? Intuitively, it will diverge if $T$ is a compact operator and $\phi$ is a trace.