# Divergence of a series involving an operator [Part II]

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $T$ be an operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Assume $r$ is the spectral radius of $T$ and $r$ is also an isolated point spectrum of $T$, $\phi$ is a finite faithful normal trace on the operator algebra generated by $T$. Can we deduce that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\phi(T^n)}{nr^n}\to\infty?$$

[Related Question: Part I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458397/divergence-of-a-series-involving-an-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't require $\phi$ to be faithful, but I assume that's the spirit of the question.

Take $H=L^2[0,1]$, $T=M_x$, i.e. multiplication by the identity function. Then $T$ is selfadjoint, $\|T\|=1$, $r=1\in\sigma(T)$. The von Neumann algebra generated by $T$ is $L^\infty[0,1]$. Let $\phi$ be integration. Then
$$
\phi(T^n)=\int_{[0,1]} x^n dx=\frac1{n+1}, 
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\phi(T^n)}{nr^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}=1
$$

If $r $ is an isolated point of the spectrum, and the only one with $|\lambda|=r $; and if $T $ is selfadjoint:  we may assume $r=1$. Then $T=P+B $, with $P $ a projection and $\|B\|<1$. Also, $T^n=P+B^n $. Then
$$
\sum_n\frac {\phi (T^n)}{n}=\sum_n\frac {\phi (B^n)}{n}+\sum_n\frac {\phi (P)}{n}.
$$
The first sum converges absolutely because $|\phi (B^n)|\leq\|\phi\|\,\|B\|^n $. The second one is harmonic. So the series diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I do want $\phi$ to be faithful. I had the condition in part I. I have already updated the question.

Comment: Without faithfullness, one can make examples where $\phi(T^n)=0$, so I agree that faithfulness is needed. Integration against a positive measure is faithful, though, so the example above answers the question. Note also that the example can be pushed, in the sense that if you take $f(x)=x^2$, then already $\sum\phi(T^n)$ converges.

Comment: Yes! What if I assume $r$ is an isolated point spectrum? I think the divergence would be right if $T$ is self-adjoint together with this extra assumption?

Comment: Yes, that case works. I've edited it into the answer.

Comment: Yes thanks. But do you think it would work if $T$ is not necessarily self-adjoint

Comment: I don't see how to predict what $\phi$ will do if there are other points in the spectrum with absolute value $r$.